# How can I access the new Serial API on Google Chrome Beta 77+?

Tags: google-chrome, serial-port, iot

I would like to use the new [Serial API](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6577673212002304#) on Chrome Beta (version 77+).  However, it's unclear to me how to reference it.

I have built a Chrome App that can do serial communication, but apparently Google is [discontinuing Chrome Apps](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html).  The [Platform Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/features#milestone=77) for Chrome suggests that the Serial API is available for Beta and Dev/Canary, but `chrome.serial` is undefined when I have typed it into the console.

Here is some functioning code from my Chrome App - it would be great to be able to re-use it for the web app:

```
let serialSettings = {
    bitrate: 115200,
    dataBits: 'eight',
    parityBit: 'no',
    stopBits: 'one',
    ctsFlowControl: false
};

function start() {
  portSelect = document.getElementById('portSelect');
  document.getElementById('disconnectButton').addEventListener("click", disconnectButtonHandler);
  chrome.serial.getDevices(function(devices) {
    buildPortSelect(devices) 
    openSelectedPort();
  });
};

//Leaving out buildPortSelect for brevity

function openSelectedPort() {
  let portSelect = document.getElementById('portSelect');
  let selectedPort = portSelect.options[portSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  let connectionInfoDisplay = document.getElementById('connectionInfoDisplay');
  for (let i = 0; i < state.eligiblePorts.length; i++) {
    if (selectedPort == state.eligiblePorts[i].path) {
      connectionInfoDisplay.innerText = "Connected to: " + selectedPort;
      chrome.serial.connect(selectedPort, serialSettings, onConnect);
      break;
    }
  }
}

let onConnect = function(connectionInfo) {
   // The serial port has been opened. Save its id to use later.
  connectionId = connectionInfo.connectionId;
}

start();
```

I would like to be able to use `chrome.serial.getDevices()` and `chrome.serial.connect()` as before, but these don't work.  Is there an alternative syntax?

Answer (score 4):

I found a few issues with your code:

- To access the serial property, instead of `chrome.serial`, use `navigator.serial`
- The snippet below compiles, however, due to what I assume to be security restriction of 'StackSnippet' service, we are not able to simulate `navigator.serial` usage completely.

```js
let serialSettings = {
  bitrate: 115200,
  dataBits: "eight",
  parityBit: "no",
  stopBits: "one",
  ctsFlowControl: false
};

function start() {
  var portSelect = document.getElementById("portSelect");
  portSelect.addEventListener("click", async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Selecting port");
    // Request a port/device from user
    const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();

    // Open and begin reading.
    await port.open({
      baudrate: 115200
    });

    const reader = port.in.getReader();
    while (true) {
      const { done, data } = await reader.read();
      if (done) break;
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("disconnectButton").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked disconnect");
  });

  navigator.serial.getPorts(function(devices) {
    buildPortSelect(devices);
    openSelectedPort();
  });
}

//Leaving out buildPortSelect for brevity

function openSelectedPort() {
  let portSelect = document.getElementById("portSelect");
  let selectedPort = portSelect.options[portSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  let connectionInfoDisplay = document.getElementById("connectionInfoDisplay");
  for (let i = 0; i < state.eligiblePorts.length; i++) {
    if (selectedPort == state.eligiblePorts[i].path) {
      connectionInfoDisplay.innerText = "Connected to: " + selectedPort;
      navigator.serial.connect(selectedPort, serialSettings, onConnect);
      break;
    }
  }
}

const onConnect = function(connectionInfo) {
  // The serial port has been opened. Save its id to use later.
  connectionId = connectionInfo.connectionId;
};

start();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="portSelect" type="button">Select a port</button>
  <div id="connectionInfoDisplay">Connection Information</div>
  <button id="disconnectButton" type="button">Disconnect</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just downloaded the Chrome 77 beta (`77.0.3865.35`), and I get `undefined` for `navigator.serial`. The [Platform Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6577673212002304) says that it's available "behind a flag", but I don't see this flag in `chrome://flags`. Any hint?

Comment: Found it. The feature to enable is chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Comment: any word on when this is supposed to be freely available and not on beta?

Answer (score 3):

Correct answer from [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759866/benjamin): 
Found it. The feature to enable is chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features